# Android Source Compiling Error, globs-build.ninja emp

Tags: android, android-source, custom-rom

I am trying to build android source from ProjectElixir CustomROM, when i run the make command, i am getting an error with an file `/out/soong/globs-build.ninja`, but this file is empty.

### Enviroment

OS: ArchLinux on WSL
RAM: 32GB
CPU: Core i7 6th Generation

### Steps to reproduce

```bash
repo init --depth=1 -u https://github.com/Project-Elixir/manifest -b UNO
repo sync -c -j$(nproc --all) --force-sync --no-clone-bundle --no-tags
# Use the localmanifest
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_flashlmdd-userdebug
mka bacon # HERE IS WHEN FAILS
```

### LocalManifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>

 <!-- Device and Common Trees -->
 <project path="device/lge/sm8150-common" name="anht3889/device_lge_sm8150-common.git" remote="github" revision="13" />
 <project path="device/lge/flash-common" name="anht3889/device_lge_flash-common.git" remote="github" revision="master" />
 <project path="device/lge/flashlmdd" name="anht3889/android_device_lge_flashlmdd.git" remote="github" revision="main" />
 <project path="device/lge/common" name="anht3889/device_lge_common.git" remote="github" revision="master" />

 <!-- Proprietary Vendor -->
 <project path="vendor/lge" name="anht3889/proprietary_vendor_lge.git" remote="github" revision="aosp" />

 <!-- Kernel Source -->
 <project path="kernel/lge/sm8150" name="anht3889/kernel_lge_sm8150_new.git" remote="github" revision="main" />

 <!-- Hardware -->
 <project path="hardware/lge" name="anht3889/android_hardware_lge.git" remote="github" revision="aosp" />

</manifest>
```

### Error log

```
22:00:51 Build sandboxing disabled due to nsjail error.
date: bad date 2023-10-16 05:00 UTC
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=14
PRODUCT_INCLUDE_TAGS=com.android.mainline
CUSTOM_VERSION=ProjectElixir_4.0_flashlmdd-14-20231016-0500-UNOFFICIAL
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_flashlmdd
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-2a-dotprod
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a76
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_OS=linux
BUILD_ID=UD1A.230803.041
OUT_DIR=/home/kurumi/elixir_v500/out
============================================
FAILED: ninja: /home/kurumi/elixir_v500/out/soong/bootstrap.ninja:12: loading '/home/kurumi/elixir_v500/out/soong/globs-build.ninja': Exec format error
subninja /home/kurumi/elixir_v500/out/soong/globs-build.ninja
```

The file is empty.

I tried to delete the out folder, do the lunch command without userdebug flag.